# failed to execute '/bin/eject'

Tags: boot, scripts, eject, systemd

Recently we failed in searching campaign for a Modem Manager for my ZTE USB modem in Ubuntu 14.04 and since then, I am getting, in my Ubuntu starting messages (probably boot scripts), a bunch of messages of the following kind:

```
systemd-udevd[2759]: failed to execute '/bin/eject' '/bin/eject /dev/ZTECdrom': No such file or directory
```

Perhaps, some command is left somewhere inappropriately. Can you point me, where and what to remove to avoid them?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy eject` and the output of `which eject`

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the package `eject` via

```
sudo apt-get install eject
```

If the drive was not present, there would be a different error message:

```
% eject /dev/cdrom1
eject: unable to find or open device for: `/dev/cdrom1'
```

Comment: Made me laugh!  +1